# How to know which process is currently downloading some stuffs on system?

Tags: python, linux, process, download

I want to write a python script for Linux that shutdowns the machine after all current downloads are over. For that I need to know which are the currently downloading processes on system. How do I know which are those processes which are downloading some stuffs from the network? Are these processes managed by operating system or are they controlled by the application software?

Comment: u may try google it. Or try to ask this at superuser.

Comment: I have googled and found a closest link to this http://kotbcorp.blogspot.in/2009/06/shutdown-after-update-in-ubuntu.html

Comment: What did u find about " how to find current downloads" and what did u tried about this.Any code sample that you wrote?

Comment: No direct hint but may be something could be find using the command `ps -ef`. A similar type of  problem is http://askubuntu.com/questions/15526/how-to-shut-down-the-computer-after-a-task-has-been-completed but not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you shold take a look at this :

http://voorloopnul.com/blog/a-python-netstat-in-less-than-100-lines-of-code/